# CVS up -dPC leaves changed files. Why?

Tags: cvs

When I'm issuing `cvs up -dPC` it should in theory update all files, overwrite modified. But when after it I issue `cvs -qn` up, it shows me number of files with prefix 'C', which means changed. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem with some outdated local copies, but couldn't find an explanation for it. I could solve it removing (or renaming) the file, then issuing the command:

`$ cvs add filename`

If there were changes you want to keep, just re-rename the file you renamed.

One note: `C` in cvs update stands for conflict. Changed files will show `M` for modified.

Comment: thanks for `C` explanation. Probably, `cvs up` doesn't do anything with conflicting files purposefully, as they are conflicting and you should resolve it before it'll be able to do something with them.

Comment: For me, it was claiming it was deleted. But it wasn't. I think CVS wasn't tracking the file anymore (for some reason I don't know why) and could not "update" the file because it was already there (though not tracked). Sometimes CVS is very confusing to me.